# display an image in awt

Tags: java, awt

I have a frame and a buffer values of the image. I couldn't display the image in the frame. The code that I used is as follows:

```
byte [] payload = new byte[payload_length];
rtp_packet.getpayload(payload);
Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Image image = toolkit.createImage(payload, 0, payload_length);  
icon = new ImageIcon(image);
iconLabel.setIcon(icon);
```

I also tried adding it directly to the frame using the code :

```
 f.setIconImage(image);
```

now how to display the image? and why it is not working?

Comment: Is this using Swing or AWT components.  `ImageIcon` is Swing, but you have added the AWT tag.

Comment: i tried in swing also...but i want it n awt...I also tried adding a canvas and displaying t...

Comment: *".but i want it n awt"*  Why?  Swing is an altogether more enabled GUI toolkit.

Comment: because i have written the rest of the program in awt..so pls help ..

Comment: *"because i have written the rest of the program in awt."*  IMO that is wasted effort.  Good luck with it.

Comment: If you just want to see the image to verify it, try: `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new ImageIcon(image));`  As with all Swing calls, you should make sure it's called in the AWT event thread, using `EventQueue.invokeLater` if necessary.

Answer (score -1):

You want to use the graphics object. Your awt frame should already have one and you call your graphics object via ...

```
            BufferedImage img = javaImage; // You replace this with your image
            Graphics g = this.getGraphics(); // this is what you need to call
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null); // you then call draw image
```

In your case you simply do

```
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null); // you can look up the parameters
```

That should do it for you.

Comment: -1 terrible answer.  1) Don't call `getGraphics()`.  It is a transient object that might be overwritten at a moments notice.  See [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) in the tutorial for the right way to approach it. 2) A `Frame` implements `ImageObserver` so `g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);` should be `g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);`.

Comment: can you be clear? should I use g.drawImage(iamge,0,0,this); or not?

Comment: the image is still not disaplayed...this is the code that i used...Image image = toolkit.createImage(payload, 0, payload_length);
     BufferedImage img = (BufferedImage) image; 
        Graphics g = img.getGraphics();       
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, mainPanel);